# How to share files between Windows 10 and Ubuntu Linux subsystem?

Tags: linux, gcc, compiler-errors, windows-subsystem-for-linux, permission-denied

I'm new to Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)

**How to share files between Windows 10 and Ubuntu Linux subsystem efficiently?**

I follow this [tutorial youtube clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5lA1UKuQbf0) and I find the file created in WSL in the following path.
`C:UsersuserAppDataLocalPackagesCanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu20.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgscLocalStaterootfshomehsuchichendesktop`

[image]

I can move the c code from WSL to win10.
However, when I move c code from win10 to WSL and compile it with GCC.
It failed and got this error message.
I have no idea how to fix it. Is it a good way to share files?

```
$ gcc -o Tree Tree.c
cc1: fatal error: Tree.c: Permission denied
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Try running Visual Studio as administrator

Comment: It doesn't work tho.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it a good way to share files?

Most certainly not.

Sorry to be harsh, but I'd recommend downvoting that YouTube video (I just did).  It should have been taken offline a few years ago, after Microsoft said [it's dangerous to do that](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/).

There's an answer in that same Microsoft devblog about the *right* way to access WSL/Linux files from Windows -- Use `\\wsl$\distroname` (e.g. `\\wsl$\Ubuntu`).

However, for your use case with Visual Studio Code, there's an even better way.  Install Microsoft's "Remote - WSL" extension (or the "Remote Development" extension, which includes "Remote - WSL") in VSCode.

Then, put your files in WSL somewhere like `~/src/myproject`.  When you need to access those files with GCC, no problem - That's a Linux tool accessing the files on a Linux filesystem.  When you need to edit the files in VSCode, just change to that directory in WSL and `code .`.  That will start VSCode in that WSL directory, with additional features for integration.

Comment: Maybe just mention (explained in the blog) that to access the <distro> root on Windows, simply type `\\wsl$\<distro>` into the explorer path bar. Likewise access C: by `/mnt/c` at the wsl cmd prompt

Comment: @dmedine See the third paragraph of my answer where I mention `\\wsl$\distroname` ;-).  And yes, `/mnt/c` works from within WSL, but my focus was really just on warning people away from the bad "Here's how you access WSL files from Explorer" side of things.  Good point, though - Either method gives you cross-system file access safely.

Comment: Whoops! Always read before posting!